# Using Razor view engine - how do I format a decimal value to have commas and two decimal places?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, string, formatting, razor

As the title suggests - I have a value in my viewmodel that is decimal. I have no control over that.  I'd like to display it as currency using the Razor View Engine.

```
$@String.Format("{0:0.00}", 1005.3422)
```

gets me part way there with:

```
$1005.34
```

but how can I get the commas in there?

Thanks

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Can you use `{0:c}` instead?  This is just standard string formatting in .NET and the "c" is for currency.  There are lots of [standard numeric string formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx).  And, of course, [custom formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx), too.

Comment: You know, I swear I'd tried that before (or I wouldn't have posted such a silly question).  Either way, I tried it now and {0:c} works perfectly.  Many Thanks

Answer (score 5):

```
$ @String.Format("{0:#,##0.00}", 1005.3422)
```

Comment: Can you describe your solution? No one will understand that unformatted line of code (intent your code with 4 spaces)

Answer (score 3):

Most of the time, when you don't get the character you're expecting with strings conversion, it can be a locale issue. For exemple, you're developing with a en-us locale, but someone comes with a fr-FR locale. Then the date, currency, etc will be formatted and parsed differently.

Comment: See this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10416553/string-format-currency

Answer (score 3):

Ideally you'd be fetching the view data from some model e.g. `public decimal ItemPrice { get; set; }`

In which case the Razor expression in your view could be `@Model.ItemPrice.ToString("c")`

The same can be used for simple ViewBag items, e.g. `@ViewBag.ItemPrice.ToString("c")`

Answer (score 1):

Or you can add at class definition

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:#,##0.00}")]
```