# Format a decimal in a view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

If I have a decimal value in a field, and I am trying to display on a page, how do I format it (I would use string.format in web forms):

```
@Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) String.Format("{0:n0}",currentItem.QualityM1))
```

That errors in VS2010 with the messae: Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7087495/using-razor-view-engine-how-do-i-format-a-decimal-value-to-have-commas-and-two).

Comment: Hi - please ignore this - just found the answer - for anyone else looking, I simply replaced it with:

 @String.format("{0:n0}",currentItem.QualityM1)
           
Thanks again, Mark

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I wouldn't do this inside the view. It would be better to centralize this and provide this information as metadata as below:

```
public class Foo { 

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:n0}")]
    public decimal Bar { get; set; }
}
```

Then use this as usual:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Bar)
```

Answer (score 15):

Do you need to use Html.DisplayFor?

Otherwise you can just do:

```
@String.Format("{0:n0}",currentItem.QualityM1)
```

Answer (score 4):

dont do in `DisplayFor`... in the class  set the atributte like this one.

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:N2}")]
    public virtual decimal Valor
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```