# MVC model formatting decimal number

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

in SQL server I have the field:

```
Price   decimal (12,4)
```

in MVC model:

```
public decimal? Price { get; set; }
```

When I add or edit price 1.1234 it will save 1.1200 in the database.
I want to save it as it is 1.1234

Comment: Any Help for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

you need to add like this -

```
 dataItem.OtherFields["Price"].ToString("0.00000")
```

for more you can check out 
 [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13285240/how-to-display-number-to-2-decimal-places-in-mvc3-c)

Comment: in view or in controller??
I did in Controller like this but not save also:  item.Price = Convert.ToDecimal(itemViewModel.Price.ToString("0.0000"));

Comment: in the models .

Comment: In Model my code like this: @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Price, new { @class = "form-control" })
how i will format??

Comment: in view you can add like this- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9721673/format-a-decimal-in-a-view

Comment: i'm not reach :(

Comment: I think Decimal will accept only 2 places or what??
have i to change to float??