# How do I convert string to Indian Money format?

Tags: c#, windows-8, .net-4.5

I am trying to convert string to India Money format like if input is "1234567" then output should come as "12,34,567"

I have written following code but its not giving the expected output.

```
 CultureInfo hindi = new CultureInfo("hi-IN");
 string text = string.Format(hindi, "{0:c}", fare);
 return text;
```

can anyone tell me how to do this?

Comment: I get the output `₹ 12,34,567.00`, which seems correct; what data type is `fare` ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10416553/string-format-currency for an example of number formatting

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If `fare` is any of `int`, `long`, `decimal`, `float` or `double` then I get the expected output of:

`₹ 12,34,567.00`.

I suspect your `fare` is actually a `string`; strings are not formatted by `string.Format`: they are *already* a string: *there is no value to format*. So: parse it first (using whatever is appropriate, maybe an invariant decimal parse), then format the parsed value; for example:

```
// here we assume that `fare` is actually a `string`
string fare = "1234567";
decimal parsed = decimal.Parse(fare, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
CultureInfo hindi = new CultureInfo("hi-IN");
string text = string.Format(hindi, "{0:c}", parsed);
```

---

Edit re comments; to get just the formatted value without the currency symbol or decimal portion:

```
string text = string.Format(hindi, "{0:#,#}", value);
```

Comment: Actually i am looking for an output in string format like 12,34,567 and not like ₹ 12,34,567.00. the above solution gives me the latter answer.

Comment: @BalrajSingh then.... why did you specify `c`? Simply: `12,34,567` is not the currency format for hi-IN.

Comment: @BalrajSingh I have added an example to show a way of getting that output

Answer (score 0):

String.Format("0:C0") for no decimal places.

As per my comment above you can achieve what you desire by cloning a numberformatinfo and set the currency symbol property to empty string

[Example can be found here - look down the bottom of the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10416553/string-format-currency)

EDIT: Here is the above linked post formatted for your question:

```
var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("hi-IN")
var numberFormatInfo = (NumberFormatInfo)cultureInfo.NumberFormat.Clone();
numberFormatInfo.CurrencySymbol = "";

var price = 1234567;
var formattedPrice = price.ToString("0:C0", numberFormatInfo); // Output: "12,34,567"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
int myvalue = 123456789;
Console.WriteLine(myvalue.ToString("#,#.##", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("hi-IN")));//output;- 12,34,56,789
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show in Razor view file, then use,

```
@String.Format(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("hi-IN"), "{0:c}", decimal.Parse("12345678", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))

// Output: ₹ 1,23,45,678.00
```