# Windows 8 metro app C# - slips a symbol in a String within the TextBox?

Tags: c#, windows, textbox

I'm making a TextBox that urge an input of amount of money. So when users type 1000 in that TextBox it will automatically become 1,000 in the TextBox. Is this possible?

Comment: you need textbox focus leave event then loop over length of text to insert ',' in it.

Comment: I have tried SelectionChanged, gives me an error

Comment: I also have tried converting String to Char and manually put the ","

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't like the lenght based solution (you need to implement more code for bigger number).

One solution found on google is that:

On XAML file:

```
<code>
<textbox x:name="PurchasePriceTextBox" text="$0.00" keydown="CurrencyTextBox_KeyDown" lostfocus="CurrencyTextBox_LostFocus" />
</code>
```

On CS file:

```
private void CurrencyTextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
char key = Convert.ToChar(e.Key);
//if the key is not 0-9 prevent the event from being handled further
if (!(key >= '0' && key <= '9'))
   e.Handled = true;  
}
private void CurrencyTextBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   var textBox = (TextBox)sender;
   decimal value = 0;
   //if the textbox is not already formatted as currency, format it
   if(Decimal.TryParse(textBox.Text.Trim(), NumberStyles.Number | NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol, CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, out value))
   {
      textBox.Text = string.Format("{0:C}", value);
   }
}
```

[Source](http://blog.evanrosebrook.com/2012/09/xaml-metro-style-numeric-only-currency.html)

Comment: And [another good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12492634/1498857) by Marc Gravell

Comment: this one is what I'm talking about!

Comment: hey, how to "select all" the TextBox once clicked?

Answer (score 0):

Make use of the textbox_TextChanged event of the text box as shown below:

```
private void textbox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (textbox.Text.Length ==4)
        {
            textbox.Text = textbox.Text.Insert(1, ",");
            return;
        }        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

On Focus Leave event just loop according to your length:

```
if (textbox.Text.Length <4)
{
    return;
}
int i = 2;
if textbox.Text.Length%2 ==0)
{
    i = 1;
}
l = textbox.Text.Length;
while(l > 3)
{
    textbox.Text = textbox.Text.Insert(i, ",");
    i+=2;
    l-=2;
}
return;
```

Comment: works on 1000 to 1,000. doesn't work on a lot amount of digits