# How to print currency with comma as in Indian format (eg: 3,20,000)

Tags: c#, crystal-reports-2010

I am printing currency with comma as in Indian format (eg: 3,20,000) 
for Ex. 320000 this is my amount but i want to print in 3,20,000 this format in Crystal Report.
What is the setting for view this amount in this format.
Thanx in Advanced

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I convert string to Indian Money format?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12492567/how-do-i-convert-string-to-indian-money-format)

Comment: Have you checked converting the string into number using formula and then specifying the format in number field properties? I have been doing the same and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the extension method i wrote when working on my project

```
public static CultureInfo EnglishIndia = new CultureInfo("en-IN");
//To use the rupee symbol please change "en-IN" to "hi-IN"

public static String ToLocalFormat(this decimal value)
{
    return string.Format(Constants.EnglishIndia, "{0:#,0.00}", value);
}
```

To use it

```
decimal amount = 100000;
var decimal_as_string = amount.ToLocalFormat();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `CultureInfo` class.

This is how you do it:

```
CultureInfo india = new CultureInfo("hi-IN");
string text = string.Format(india , "{0:c}", "320000"); // ₹ 3,20,000
```