# Get Float value with Comma separtor

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-ce, sql-server-ce-3.5

Am new to `Sql server ce`. my table have float value. I want select float with comma separated and decimal position. like this

table name **table1**

```
 val
 1220333
 222
 36535
```

I want result like this

```
val
12,20,333.00
222.00
36,535.00
```

like indian Rupees

Am using `Sql server ce 3.5`

Comment: General advice is to format your data in the presentation layer.

Comment: @destination-data i need load this value in drop down. so only i tried in query

Comment: Check this link and hope it helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12492567/how-do-i-convert-string-to-indian-money-format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE 
    (val int)
;

INSERT INTO @Table1
    (val)
VALUES
    (1220333),
    (222),
    (36535)
;
select convert(varchar(50), CAST(val as money), -1) amount from @Table1

select FORMAT(CAST(val AS MONEY),'N','en-in') amount from @Table1
```

OR

Function

```
create function to_indian_currency(@n decimal(25,5))
returns varchar(100) as
BEGIN
declare @a varchar(100) = cast(@n as varchar(100))
declare @dec_part varchar(100) = 
(select substring(@a, charindex('.',@a), len(@a)-charindex('.',@a)+1))
declare @int_part varchar(100) = (select left(@a, charindex('.',@a)-1))
declare @f int = cast(@int_part as bigint)%1000
declare @q int = cast(@int_part as bigint)/1000
declare @final varchar(100) = ''
while @q > 0
begin
set @final = cast(@q%100 as varchar) + ',' + @final
set @q = @q/100
end
RETURN @final + cast(@f as varchar) + @dec_part
END
```

**select dbo.to_indian_currency(val) from @Table1**

Comment: `1,220,333.00` and OP wants `12,20,333.00`

Comment: After adding locale it is OK . But I am not sure that FORMAT is available in [SQL Server CE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174077%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Its Show Error. The Function not recognized. Function name Format

Comment: now try this function it will work in CE 3.5 @Sathish