# How to get Indian currency format using C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to convert Numbers into Indian Currency format.

```
 public static string ConvertStringToRupee(string Amount)
    {
        float num = float.Parse(Amount);
        NumberFormatInfo provider = new NumberFormatInfo
        {
            CurrencyGroupSeparator = ",",
            CurrencyGroupSizes = new int[] { 3, 2 },
            CurrencySymbol = ""
        };
        return num.ToString("N", provider);
    }
```

It's perfect for 5 digit. If it is exceeding, it takes three digit.
For example it shows **3,345,507.00** instead of **33,45,507.00**. But I need 
33,45,507.00.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12492567/how-do-i-convert-string-to-indian-money-format

Answer (score 0):

To print indian currecy symbol use the below code

`string fare = "1234567";
decimal parsed = decimal.Parse(fare, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
CultureInfo hindi = new CultureInfo("hi-IN");
string text = string.Format(hindi, "{0:c}", parsed);`