# input string was not in correct format c# displaying a price on a label

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

Im new to c# and im trying to display a price of a product on a label, however when i run the page i get the error " input string was not in correct format"
i have set the price as float.

this is the current code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Text;
using WebApplication1.DataAccess;


namespace WebApplication1
{
public partial class Store : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GenerateControls();
    }

    private void GenerateControls()
    {
        ArrayList productsList = Connection.GetProductsByType("%");

        foreach (Products products in productsList)
        {
            Panel productPanel = new Panel();
            Image image = new Image { ImageUrl = products.Image, CssClass = " ProductsImage" };
            Literal literal = new Literal() { Text = "<br/>" };
            Literal literal2 = new Literal() { Text = "<br/>" };
            Label lblName = new Label { Text = products.Name, CssClass = "ProductsName" };
            Label lblPrice = new Label
           {
              Text = String.Format("{0.0.00}", products.Price + "<br/>"),
              CssClass = "ProductsPrice"
           };

            TextBox textBox = new TextBox
            {
                ID = products.Id.ToString(),
                CssClass = "ProductsTextBox",
                Width = 60,
                Text = "0"
            };

            RegularExpressionValidator regex = new RegularExpressionValidator
            {
                ValidationExpression = "^[0-9]*",
                ControlToValidate = textBox.ID,
                ErrorMessage = "Please enter number."
            };

            productPanel.Controls.Add(image);
            productPanel.Controls.Add(literal);
            productPanel.Controls.Add(lblName);
            productPanel.Controls.Add(literal2);
            productPanel.Controls.Add(lblPrice);
            productPanel.Controls.Add(textBox);
            productPanel.Controls.Add(regex);

            pnlProducts.Controls.Add(productPanel);

        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Where *exactly* did you get the error? (Note that a price should usually be decimal, not float... That's not the problem you're seeing, but it's *a* problem.)

Comment: i get the error at : Label lblPrice = new Label, and thank you, i shall change that

Comment: Why do you still use an `ArrayList`? It's time to use a `List<Products>` instead.

Comment: And what do you think `{0.0.00}` does as a format string? Look carefully.

Comment: how can i correct this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the error at

```
String.Format("{0.0.00}", products.Price + "<br/>")
```

That's not a valid format string, you either have to use:

```
String.Format("{0:0.00}", products.Price + "<br/>")
```

or

```
String.Format("{0}", products.Price.ToString("0.00") + "<br/>")
```

As an aside, you can put the `<br/>` also into the `String.Format` for better readability:

```
String.Format("{0:0.00}<br/>", products.Price)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this:

```
 Label lblPrice = new Label
 {
     Text = String.Format("{0:C}", products.Price + "<br/>"),
     CssClass = "ProductsPrice"
 };
```

Using {0:C) specifies that the string should be a Currency format.

See: [String format currency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10416553/string-format-currency)