# C# DataGridView £ instead of $

Tags: c#, datagridview, currency

I am using a DataGridView to display data from a database. I am trying to format a column to display as a currency with a £ symbol rather than a $.

I am currently using this code:

```
this.dgvPRL.Columns[4].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "c";
```

however it displays with a $ not £.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the current culture currency settings, but change the symbol for that data grid view column, in addition to `Format` property you need to set [DataGridViewCellStyle.FormatProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellstyle.formatprovider(v=vs.110).aspx) property like this (make sure to include `using System.Globalization;`):

```
var info = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.Clone();
info.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol = "£";
this.dgvPRL.Columns[4].DefaultCellStyle.FormatProvider = info;
this.dgvPRL.Columns[4].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "c";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the current culture.

Check this question:
[String format currency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10416553/string-format-currency)

Comment: Thank you that is very helpful and works with my other variables: but im not sure how to do this for a DataGridView