# Formatting a Nullable Decimal in a Razor View in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC app. This app is using Razor in the views. I am trying to display a `decimal?`. The twist on this is that I do NOT want to show decimals. In other words, if the nullable decimal value is `567.89`, I just want to display `567`. Currently, I have a plain old:

```
<div class="icon">@Model.Count</div>
```

This approach displays `567.89`. How do I format this nullable decimal to only show the whole number portion?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you do Decimal.ToInt32

Comment: Maybe this question can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7087495/using-razor-view-engine-how-do-i-format-a-decimal-value-to-have-commas-and-two

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use String.Format to display the decimal? with out the decimals.

```
@String.Format("{0:0}", 567.89)
```

Will display 567

Comment: What will this display if the value is NULL?

Comment: The value will be an empty string.

Comment: If you want to provide a default value for null, you can use the null-coalescing operator on the second param: `@string.Format("{0:0}", nullableDecimal ?? 0)`.

Comment: You can also consider applying the `DisplayFormat` attribute to your property (setting `DataFormatString` and `NullDisplayText` properties) and using `@DisplayFor(m => m.Count)`